# django.contrib.auth login() returning None issue

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, web-development-server

I am new to django and I have been trying to implement login system for my django project.

```
    template_name = 'rest_framework/login.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
        print (login(request,user))
        login(request,user)
        return redirect('core:home')
    return render(request, template_name)
```

For some reason, the *login* function which I have imported from django.contrib.auth is returning None even when user has the correct user object after authenticating and request has POST request object. This is resulting in the user not getting added to the session and hence when I redirect it to **core:home**, I am getting AnonymousUser in request.user. Help would be appreciated.

PS: I have written a custom backend for authentication.

Comment: `login(..)` is supposed to return `Nothing`. It is only `authenticate` that checks credentials, and returns `None` if the credentails fail.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `login()` method hasn't a return type. You must check result of `authenticate()` method before. If authentication is failed, `authenticate()` method returns None. In this situation means that, there is no user with provided username and password. So if result of `authenticate()` is None, you can give warning and don't call `login()` method.

Comment: Oh thanks. I didnt know about this. But, the issue still remains, authenticate() is giving me the right user object. But, when I redirect it to a different URL, I am getting AnonymousUser